# When was LotFP grindhouse edition published?

Tags: history-of-gaming, osr, lamentations-of-the-flame-princess

I have some trouble finding bibliographic information for Lamentations of the flame princess grindhouse edition referee book, or the set as a whole. The pdf of the referee book contains no bibliographical information, and the free rules and magic book has the same lack.

When was the referee book published?

Answer (score 4):

[According to rpg.net's gaming index](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=15635), the grindhouse edition boxed set (and thus the referee book) was published in 2011.